# How to load load google's api.js file in to my vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate google calendar in to my vue project. I am following https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-integrate-google-calendar/31218/7  this and there I found this example https://jsfiddle.net/andrisv/nqwdymee/.

my vue file is like this,

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class='authentification'>
      <h2>VueJS + Google Calendar Example</h2>
      Authentification
      <button v-if='!authorized' @click="handleAuthClick">Sign In</button>
      <button v-if='authorized' @click="handleSignoutClick">Sign Out</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button v-if='authorized' @click="getData">Get Data</button>
    <div class="item-container" v-if="authorized && items">
      <pre v-html="items"></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>



<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

<script>

  const CLIENT_ID = '';
  const API_KEY = '';
  const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'];
  const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: undefined,
        api: undefined,
        authorized: false
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.api = gapi;
      this.handleClientLoad();
    },
    methods: {
      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      handleClientLoad() {
        this.api.load('client:auth2', this.initClient);
      },

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      initClient() {
        let vm = this;
        vm.api.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(_ => {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          vm.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(vm.authorized);
        });
      },

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      handleAuthClick(event) {
        Promise.resolve(this.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn())
          .then(_ => {
            this.authorized = true;
          });
      },

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      handleSignoutClick(event) {
        Promise.resolve(this.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut())
          .then(_ => {
            this.authorized = false;
          });
      },

      /**
       * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
       * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
       * appropriate message is printed.
       */
      getData() {
        let vm = this;

        vm.api.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(response => {
          vm.items = this.syntaxHighlight(response.result.items);
          console.log(vm.items);
        });
      },
      syntaxHighlight(json) {
        if (typeof json != 'string') {
          json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2);
        }
        json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, match => {
          var cls = 'number';
          if (/^"/.test(match)) {
            if (/:$/.test(match)) {
              cls = 'key';
            } else {
              cls = 'string';
            }
          } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'boolean';
          } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'null';
          }
          return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
        });
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

I am getting `gapi is not defined` error, so I loaded the https://apis.google.com/js/api.js as a script. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. Thanks. But still I couldn't load it in the right way, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [vue-gapi](https://github.com/cedpoilly/vue-gapi) and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.gapi = window.gapi
```

When you load gapi as a script you need to access it through `window`

Also don't load the script async, do it like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried your answer. But now I am getting  `Cannot read property 'load' of undefined` error.

Comment: When I add console.log(window.gapi) it prints undefined.

Comment: log ```window.gapi ``` and see if it is undefined

Comment: Oh okay just saw your comment

Comment: console.log(window) and see what is there

Comment: I updated the answer. Don't load the script async. It hasn't loaded by the time you use it

Comment: `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>` I used this, but I am still getting the error. `console.log(window)` print the object.

Comment: Have you tried just ```this.api = gapi``` after changing it from async? Other than that I can't think of anything else

Comment: Well one more thing I thought of. Have you tried waiting for gapi? it is possible that it has not loaded by the time you access it.

Comment: Can you please let me know how could I do it

Comment: Im not sure honestly since I do way more react than vue but there should be a way to conditionally render your script ```if(window.gap1) //run code``` If anything set a timeout and see if window.gapi is there after a second and then you will know if that is the problem